# Xcode 8.0 where is the NSManagedObject subclass template

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

After updating to Xcode 8.0, I want to add some `NSManagedObject` subclasses to my project.

In the previous versions, there was a template with the same name that helped to create the classes for all the core data entities at a time. But I do not find the option under the list of new file templates in Xcode 8.0

Do I need to create my own template? Or there is an other way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your model, and click on Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass[image]

Comment: this creates it in objective c for me, any way to change the language?

Comment: Yes, look in the file inspector panel when the data model il open. You can choose the language here